# Can't get the Linkedin ID after login successfully with Linkedin on Android app?

Tags: android, authentication, oauth, linkedin-api

I use Linkedin to connect to my application. I need the userId, the token and token_secret. I get the two token but I can't get the id of the current user logged!

The line: `p.getId();` send me a null.

Here my code:

```
String verifier = intent.getData().getQueryParameter("oauth_verifier");

    LinkedInAccessToken accessToken = oAuthService.getOAuthAccessToken(liToken, verifier);
    client = factory.createLinkedInApiClient(accessToken);
    client.postNetworkUpdate("LinkedIn Android app test");
    Person p = client.getProfileForCurrentUser();

    System.out.println("TEST "+client.getProfileForCurrentUser());

    System.out.println("Token  "+accessToken.getToken());

    System.out.println("Secret  "+accessToken.getTokenSecret());

    System.out.println("NOM "+p.getLastName() + ", PRENOM" + p.getFirstName());

    Person profile = client.getProfileForCurrentUser(EnumSet.of(ProfileField.FIRST_NAME, ProfileField.LAST_NAME, ProfileField.CERTIFICATIONS_ID));
    //System.out.println("IDDDDD"+profile.getId());

    Connections connections = client.getConnectionsForCurrentUser();
    System.out.println("Total connections fetched:" + connections.getTotal());
    for (Person person : connections.getPersonList()) {
            System.out.println(person.getId() + ":" + person.getFirstName() + " " + person.getLastName() + ":" + person.getHeadline());
    }
```

Help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please replace this line,

```
Person profile = client.getProfileForCurrentUser(EnumSet.of(ProfileField.FIRST_NAME, ProfileField.LAST_NAME, ProfileField.CERTIFICATIONS_ID));
```

with,

```
Person profile = client.getProfileForCurrentUser(EnumSet.of(ProfileField.FIRST_NAME, ProfileField.LAST_NAME, ProfileField.ID));
```

For getting Id, `ProfileField.ID` should be used instead of `ProfileField.CERTIFICATIONS_ID`

Answer (score 0):

**Modify this:**

```
Person profile = client.getProfileForCurrentUser(EnumSet.of(ProfileField.FIRST_NAME, ProfileField.LAST_NAME, ProfileField.CERTIFICATIONS_ID));
    //System.out.println("IDDDDD"+profile.getId());
```

**with this:**

```
final Person user_Profile = client.getProfileForCurrentUser(EnumSet.of(ProfileField.ID)); person = client.getProfileById(user_Profile.getId(), EnumSet.of(ProfileField.FIRST_NAME,
                            ProfileField.LAST_NAME));
System.out.println("IDDDDD"+profile.getId());
```